# Neo4J how to show label on node

Tags: graph, neo4j

I have recently started database with neo4j.
I understanded more or less anything that i searched and i applicated it, but there's this thing that i dont know how to risolve.
So, here's my question: how can i show on the various nodes the label that i give them instead of numbers?
For example from this:

[image]

To this:

[image]

(ps: sorry but my reputation is to low so i can't post images without external link)

Answer (score 2):

If you click the label in the top left. Then click one of the properties on the bottom, that should change what the nodes say on them.

Answer (score 2):

The issue here is that a node can have more than one label, so which one would you show.
For example, a car might have labels Vehicle, Car, Mini. In code you would put these into an object hierarchy.
The way I get round this issue is to have a parameter nodeType which I set to be the lowest type on the hierarchy, so for this example it would be 'Mini'.

The parameter nodeType can then be set to display, so the graph would appear to display the Label

Comment: Hi, do you have any news on this? Is it possible to use caption: "<type>" for nodes? (I wanted to create such question but I think it's pointless and your workaround still stands)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure that's possible yet. You can use `{property}` or `<type>` in caption.

What you could do is is to use the cascading capabilities of the GRASS to give the different labels different colors, fonts, widths, border-colors etc.

Comment: you need to remember that the Order you add Labels to Neo matters, as the UI uses the first label to set the colour/size attributes